# Resharper code cleanup is rearranging a commented out method

Tags: resharper

When I run Resharper 10.0.2 code cleanup on a file containing this commented out TestMethod, it starts with this:

```
    ////[TestMethod]
    ////public void ParseuploadFileSetResponse()
    ////}
    ////    powerShellAdapter.ParseUploadFileSetResponse(Collection<PSObject>);
    ////    var powerShellAdapter = new SecureFTCmdletAdapter(proxyDomain, proxyAlias, secretPassword, powerShellInvoker.Instance);
    ////{
```

And ends with this:

```
    ////{
    ////    var powerShellAdapter = new SecureFTCmdletAdapter(proxyDomain, proxyAlias, secretPassword, powerShellInvoker.Instance);
    ////    powerShellAdapter.ParseUploadFileSetResponse(Collection<PSObject>);
    ////}
    ////public void ParseuploadFileSetResponse()

    ////[TestMethod]
```

If my TestMethod isn't commented out, it leaves it alone. Any idea what's going wrong? To be clear, I want it to not rearrange my commented out code.